# Sandbox IPN being Queued What does that mean?

Tags: paypal

I have setup my ipn after a few tests using the IPN simulator.

The Simulation works Perfectly however when i do a normal payment using the sandbox accounts the ipn gets Queued and thus the ipn cannot process my stuff on server side.

Why is it getting queued, i have verified the url is correct on the IPN History.
Or is this just an issue with Sandbox Test Accounts? If the simulation works should it then work in real life situations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the next post about this problem so we can be sure there was an internal Sandbox error. I had the same even though my script worked fine few days ago. Yesterday I asked PayPal's technical support for help. 
This night (11.05.2015 3:49 GMT+1) I got response mail that my problem has been solved - and it really has. Now all of my 'queued' IPNs are 'Sent'.
If they did a global fix then yours should be good too.
If not - try to contact technical support.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Well mine seem to e going through but really slowly like hours wait. I just hope it won't do that on live. The simulation worked fine so I don't think it's a problem on my end .

Comment: Some time ago mine was going through slowly too. But like you said - it took few hours. I didn't care. This time it took whole weekend so I decided to request an assistance.
You shouldn't get this kind of problems on live.

Comment: Just to be clear: IPNs are always queued, on both sandbox and live, and PayPal works from this queue to deliver these events to you. PayPal had some issues this weekend with how quickly it was able to clear the queue on the sandbox. These issues (and therefore delays) are less likely to happen on live, and tend to be addressed more quickly, but IPN is inherently an queued asynchronous event. Delays of minutes to hours have happened on live before and will happen again. Despite the name, do NOT rely on IPNs being instant!